# Laravel 5 where condition to get pass 30 days worth of records

Tags: laravel, date, time, where-clause, php-carbon

I have a date column in the instances table with varchar datatype stored as d-m-Y. In my where condition I am trying to fetch records for just past 30 days only.

```
$backdate = Carbon::parse('-30 days')->toDateString();

$date30DaysBack = Carbon::parse($backdate)->format('d-m-Y'); 

$adverts = DB::table('adverts') 
->where(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'), '>=',$date30DaysBack)
```

The full query

```
$adverts  = DB::table('adverts')
            ->select(DB::raw('(SELECT IF(ext = \'jpeg\', CONCAT(fullpath, \'_1.\', ext), (CONCAT(fullpath,\'.\',ext))) as fullpath FROM advertsstorage where uid_dir = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id ASC limit 1)as fullpath, adverts.*, domains.location,instances.date'))                
            ->join('domains','adverts.domain', '=' ,'domains.domain')
            ->join('advertiser_domains','domains.id', '=' ,'advertiser_domains.domain_id')
            ->join('advertisers','advertiser_domains.advertiser_id', '=' ,'advertisers.u_id')
            ->join('instances','adverts.ad_uid','=','instances.ad_uid')
            ->join('urls','instances.u_id','=','urls.id')
            ->join('sites','urls.sites_id','=','sites.id')     
            ->where('advertisers.u_id', '=',$advertiserID)
            ->where(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'), '>=',Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('d-m-Y'))

            ->orderBy(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'), 'DESC')

            ->get();
```

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I would like to get 30days worth of record from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `DATEDIFF` [method](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

```
$adverts  = DB::table('adverts')
    ->select(DB::raw('(SELECT IF(ext = \'jpeg\', CONCAT(fullpath, \'_1.\', ext), (CONCAT(fullpath,\'.\',ext))) as fullpath FROM advertsstorage where uid_dir = adverts.ad_uid ORDER BY id ASC limit 1)as fullpath, adverts.*, domains.location,instances.date'))                
    ->join('domains','adverts.domain', '=' ,'domains.domain')
    ->join('advertiser_domains','domains.id', '=' ,'advertiser_domains.domain_id')
    ->join('advertisers','advertiser_domains.advertiser_id', '=' ,'advertisers.u_id')
    ->join('instances','adverts.ad_uid','=','instances.ad_uid')
    ->join('urls','instances.u_id','=','urls.id')
    ->join('sites','urls.sites_id','=','sites.id')     
    ->where('advertisers.u_id', '=',$advertiserID)

    ->where(DB::raw('DATEDIFF( now(), STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y") )'), '<=', 30)

    ->orderBy(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'), 'DESC')

    ->get();
```

Comment: let me try that and see.

Comment: what database do you use? mysql?

Comment: Awesome, Bingo! As soon as I used DATEDIFF method , it worked as expected. Thanks all, and thanks to @huuuk

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
Carbon has subDays function by which you can get past 30 days data

```
$date30DaysBack= Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('d-m-Y'); 
$today = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'); 

 $adverts = DB::table('adverts') 
   ->whereBetween(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'),[$date30DaysBack,$today])->get()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, I do get the right expected date with both the way `Carbon::parse('-30 days')->toDateString();`  and ` Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('d-m-Y')` but still effected records are going over the 30days

Comment: do u have join in your query?

Comment: Yes , I have join in my query

Comment: Please post your whole query

Comment: If I changed to '<=' its a empty results

Comment: Please check my answer @sanainfotech

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)?

You can use the subtraction modifier for this; `Carbon::now()->subDays(30);`.

Would look something like this in your code:

```
$adverts = DB::table('adverts')->where(DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(instances.date,"%d-%m-%Y")'), '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('d-m-Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks, subDays and -30 days both get expected date. but still my the results are going above 30 days